# Using facebook graph api, fetching users tagged in photo and realted photos

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have got a requirement for facebook based application, wherein

- We need to fetch a given photo.
- Identify all the users tagged in that photo and then...
- Fetch all the photos in which any of the tagged user is appearing.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this using facebook's graph api?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can access photo properties, including tags, as per the Graph API documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo).

To fetch all the photos of a given user, you will need to request the user_photo_video_tags [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) from them when they authorize your application.

If all photos/users involved in the process belong to/have authorized your application then it should work. Otherwise, it could be fraught with problems, e.g. if said "given photo" isn't public (i.e. visible to "Everyone"), you will need to identify its owner and request the user_photos permission from them. Similarly, friends can tag their friends in photos, so you can't assume you'll be able to access all photos of any tagged user.

Good luck! :)